# Accessing share with ACLs using groups instead of explicitly granting user names not working?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, access-control-list

I've setup a share on a windows server.  \ServerName\ShareName.  I've granted permissions for the share to "X Department".  I also have an ACL for that "D:\FS\Sharename" folder granting "X Department" access.

However, when I try to access with a user from "X Department", I get an access denied error.  When I manually add a user which is part of "X Department" to that ACL, it works fine however.

Comment: Did you create the group at the time of creating the share? If so, has the user logged off an back on in order to reflect the new group membership in their access token?

Comment: @joeqwerty No, I didn't

Comment: That's what you need to do then. Any change in user group membership requires a logoff/logon to reflect those changes in the users access token.

Comment: Should have been more clear, didn't create the group at the time of the share, so that isn't it

Comment: OK, remove the user from the ACL and then look at the Effective Access for the user and for the group (separately). That should give you some idea of what's wrong.

Comment: I did and it showed me that the user had permissions via the group

Comment: OK, so what are the Share permissions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27658/discussion-between-brett-g-and-joeqwerty).

Comment: do you still need help?

Comment: @AsafShazar Yes

Comment: @BrettG come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27753/try-this)

Comment: answered you there :)@BrettG

Comment: Dumb question - do you have both a locally and globally (AD) defined "X Department"?

Comment: If the user is member of a large amount of groups (120+) and logged into a Win7 PC, the Kerberos maximum token size might be reached.

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of your NTFS ACL and share ACL? Simply adding `Department X` doesn't mean it'll work. There might be other ACEs at play that would prevent a user from getting access. Also, does it work for anyone at all, or is it just a few users of `Department X`?

Comment: Did you grant these permissions through right click > properties > security?

Answer (score -2):

The users may be set to not inherit permissions from the Group. please check that.

Comment: Mmm... maybe you should provide information on "how" to check that?